# DFS and BFS not working properly

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Hello I have problem with BFS and DFS. This is my implementation based on algorithm found on the internet. The problem is that in my case it only moves vertex which I start with at the beginning, doesn't do changes of the remaining sequence.

Graph representation as an adjacency matrix

```
struct vertice {
    int index;
    double *arrOfWeights;
};

struct Graph {
    int size;
    vertice *v;
};
```

DFS algorithm:

```
   void tempDFS(Graph &g, int s, bool visited[]) {
        visited[s] = true;
        cout << s << ",";
        int i;
        for(i=0; i< g.size; i++)
            if (!visited[i])
                tempDFS(g, i, visited);
    }


    void DFS(Graph &g, int s) {
        bool *visited = new bool[g.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < g.size; i++)
            visited[i] = false;

        tempDFS(g, s, visited);

        cout << endl;
    }
```

BFS algorithm

```
void BFS(Graph &g, int s) {
    bool *visited = new bool[g.size];
    for(int i = 0; i < g.size; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    queue<int> q;

    visited[s] = true;
    q.push(s);

    while(!q.empty()) {
        s = q.front();
        cout << s << ",";
        q.pop();

        for(int i=0; i<g.size; i++) {
            if(!visited[i]) {
                visited[i] = true;
                q.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You have a very strange graph - it has vertices, but no edges (or rather, your algorithms work as if there's an edge between every pair of vertices). Where's that adjacency matrix? It's nowhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by "it only moves vertex"? What moves vertex where? Nothing is being moved anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: I'm guessing graph has an array of vertice, vertice has an array of weights, so there is a weight/distance/edge from every vertice to every other vertice (including itself). The error prone raw arrays have errors -- try std::vector.  Give us a main which initializes a basic graph and actually does a search (and tell us what answer it should have found, as well as what answer it did find). Also the spelling is bugging me -- singular "vertex" plural "vertices" https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/vertex.html